# How to determine if a function f is in theta(g)

Tags: big-o

Full disclosure: This is a homework problem. I'm honestly freaking out a little that it's evaded me for so long when it seems so simple.

Okay, the question is, f(n) = n^2*log(n), g(n) = n^2.1. Is f in theta(g)?

I just need to come up with constants c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub> so that past a certain n<sub>0</sub>, f(n) <= c<sub>1</sub>g(n) <= c<sub>2</sub>f(n). But I'm not even sure f is in theta(g) at all. I'm that confused.

Comment: @John: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember, to prove f(n) is in theta(g(n)), you can take two different approaches:

1. Prove f is in O(g) and prove g is in O(f).
2. Prove f is in O(g) and prove f is in BigOmega(g).

Answer (score 0):

First note the wording. "Is f in theta(g)". This means they want you to first make an educated guess on whether or not it is true.

Counter question: is theta(n) the same as theta(n * log(n))? We know the answer to that one... no they are not (for otherwise comparison based sorting would be linear for instance). What does this suggest on your question?

To prove the claim, follow the other answer by MahlerFive. For completeness, to attempt to disprove the claim, suppose an enemy has come up with constants c1 and c2. Now our goal is to show that despite what constants the enemy has come up (that is, for all c1 and c2) there are no n0 fulfilling the bound. In other words, show that there is no way you can choose c1 and c2. The trick in your case is probably centered around the log(n) factor in the f function. log(n) is monotonically increasing suggesting we can make that factor arbitrarily big by plugging in a larger n-value.

I hope this gets you going a little while still having the satisfaction of solving the problem yourself. If I am totally wrong, I am sure other readers will correct me.

Comment: I was drawn to "no" as an answer as well, but when I look at the plots of f and g: http://bit.ly/a4fmet, they look like if I multiply g by a big enough number (e.g. 10) it'll eventually overcome f for all x east of the intersection. And same with f. Is looking at plots a bad way to approach these questions?

Comment: Also, following your approach, I understand that I need to find n, expressed in terms of n0, c1 and c2, such that f(n) > g(n), right? But solving for n requires isolating n in 10log(n) = c1 * n^0.1...and I just don't think there's a simple way to do that. It shouldn't be so complicated right? Tell me I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: My bad that I did not see it was a power of 2.1 and not 2.0! Then it might be true or false. Looking a plots may be a way to get a feeling for the growth. My hunch for n^0.1 vs lg(n) is that these factors are the same.

Comment: Ok, one way to attack it is by little-oh and observing the limit as n goes to infinity, http://bit.ly/bsR9JJ and note that f(x) = o(g(x)) by this. This automatically establishes f(x) = O(g(x)) but it also makes it impossible that it is also theta. So it seems my hunch was wrong.